# DevOps Pipeline fails - Cannot import key file: [XXX].pfx

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have been trying to create a build pipeline in Azure DevOps. While I am able to build a basic console app project, I have been getting issues when I added pfx files into the project app.

The console app project has been enabled for ClickOnce, which required to have a *.pfx key file.

When I set a basic build pipeline, but it appears to keep on failing. I get this message:

> Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: [XXXX].pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_FE357D179B4A2D91
>
> error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: [XXXX].pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_FE357D179B4A2D91

How do I import the pfx to get the build to succeed?
Appreciate any insights/directions for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi the.herbert, any update on this issue, did you get a chance to implement the solution that Bevan suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

If you're making your PFX file available to the pipeline just add a Powershell task before the main task

```
#Import the PFX certificate file and password. Read the thumbprint into variable
$Thumbprint = (Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -FilePath Certificate.pfx -Password $pwd).Thumbprint

Write-Host $Thumbprint

#Rest of Script below or set environment variable for rest of Pipeline
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Thumbprint]$Thumbprint"
```

If you need it, you can pass the thumbprint to the rest of the pipeline with the last line or you can hard code the thumbprint where required.

I store my certificates in Azure KeyVault. If you do/would like to do the same, I have a post here for it: [Access certificate thumprint from Azure DevOps variable group connected to Key vaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436209/access-certificate-thumprint-from-azure-devops-variable-group-connected-to-key-v/55931220#55931220)

Comment: How can one add a PowerShell task like this? Should I commit the script to the repository?

Comment: I just have a Powershell or Azure Powershell task and use an in-line script. It depends if in-line scripts are acceptable where you work or if you need everything in source control. Either approach will work.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now, I had just started with Azure DevOps and was not sure where the script could be put. Now I see it can simply be put inline in the configuration file.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this doesn't fix the problem.  I have added a script, which succeeds, but how is this supposed to help the pipeline?  The error message still appears.  I don't see how this script does anything but get a thumbprint. So how does it help?

Comment: Line 2 actually installs the certificate the the hosted agent which can then be used by the rest of the pipeline. For my use case (and a lot of others), once installed you just need to declare the thumbprint in your command or application. Given the certificate is installed, the agent is now a trusted endpoint for your remote application/service.

Feel free to share what you're trying to achieve and I can see if there's a different approach or output that suits your scenario

Comment: I was able to get it to work, but only by using a self-hosted agent, and one that is running using my own windows credentials.  I just did this as a test, but I don't having to use a self-hosted agent. I think there's an issue with the project referencing the right certificate.  I get the feeling the script you provided works, but that the build task is not using that certificate.